# JUnit test Custom exception that throws @httpStatus

Tags: java, spring, junit, powermockito

I would like to test that my custom exception is thrown when I call a method like that:

```
private MyObject queryDatabase(String request, String end){
    HttpEntity myEntity = new NStringEntity(request, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response response = restClient.performRequest("GET", end,Collections.emptyMap(), myEntity)

    MyObject myObject = mapper.readValue(response.getEntity().getContent(), MyObject.Class);
    if(myObject.getFunctions().isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyResultException("Empty result");
    }
    return myObject;
}
```

My `EmptyResultException` Class :

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public Class EmptyResultException() extends RuntimeException(){
    ...
}
```

I'm just starting with JUnit and I have tried :

```
@Mock MyService myservice;

@Test(expected=EmptyResultException.class)
public void shouldReturnException() {
    when(myService.queryDatabase(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(new MyObject());
}
```

It's not working. The behavior I want to try is in `private` method. It seems I should use Powermock for such cases. However, I have read it is not good to test `private` method so I would like to change my method to `public`. Any help please?

EDIT : My full implementation :

I have a Restcontroller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping...
public class MyController {

    @Autowired 
    MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping...
    public MyObject findObject(@Valid DtoParameters parameters){
      return myService.executeQuery(parameters);
   }
   }
```

And in myService Class :

```
@Service
public class MyService{

public MyObject executeQuery(DtoParameters parameters){
 return 
    queryDatabase(parameters.buildRequest(),parameters.buildEnd());

}
}
```

Comment: The private method `queryDatabase()` would be tested as a part of the calling method (which I'm assuming is public). You can simply verify the response in the calling method.

Comment: Are you testing `MyService`, or mocking it?  You can't do both simultaneously.

Comment: I'm testing that my service throws exception when It returns empty objects.. am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @user2004685 yes the calling method is public. Could you explain more what mean by simply verify the response in the calling method ?

Comment: @John Could you please include the implementation of your `public` method here?

Comment: @ user2004685 I have updated my post with my whole implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class under test is `MyService`, it shouldn't have a `@Mock`.

I don't know your whole implementation, but let's assume `MyService` have injected dependencies (like your `mapper`)

First I would mock the mapper and inject it in `MyService`:

```
@Mock
private ObjectMapper mapper;

@InjectMocks
private MyService myService;
```

For this to work, your test class need to use the mockito runner. You can annotate your class with this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

The mocks will be injected into MyService.
Now you can mock your mapper to return an empty object:

```
when(mapper.readValue(any(),any())).thenReturn(new MyObject());
myService.queryDatabase("request", "end")
```

when calling queryDatabase, this should call the mock inside.

If you were trying to test your rest controller, it is a different way. What I suggested is a unit test on MyService. If you want to test the controller, you should do it with a `SpringRunner`, `SpringBootTest` and `MockMvc`. But first, unit test your service, and add other tests on your controller later. For the controller, you would annotate MyService with `@MockBean` and throw, or `Autowire` it and `@MockBean` the mapper inside to return an empty object like the unit test.

Check this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

---

old answer:

You could change your method to `protected`, assuming your test is in the same package as the class you are testing, you will be able to mock it.

To mock your method, you need to write it like this:

```
when(myService.queryDatabase(anyString(),anyString())).thenThrow(EmptyResultException.class);
```

You forgot to use the `when` method to wrap your call.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I don't get something : if you tenThrow the EmptyResultException directly, the test will always be ok , is that right ?

Comment: yes, you need to complete your test. Your class under test is `MyService`? If that's the case, you shouldn't have the `@Mock` on it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes Myservice is the class that contains queryDatabase method(). If the test is always ok and always pass, it means it is not relevant right ?

Comment: when you annotate with @Mock, it doesn't create your real object. You shouldn't annotate your class under test with this annotation. I updated my answer with what you should do.

Comment: If you were trying to test your rest controller, it is a different way. What I suggested is a unit test on MyService. If you want to test the controller, you should do it with a SpringRunner SpringBootTest and MockMvc . But first, unit test your service, and add other tests on your controller later. For the controller, you would annotation MyService with @MockBean. Check this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: No I want to test that my custom exception is thrown when queryDatabase method return empty result.

Comment: Thank you, it works, you help me a lot to understand how to test a service.